# Structure of Data Table in Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am storing a DataTable in Session. In what structure does the DataTable stores in session?
for eg, if I store username as
Session["username"] I can fetch it easily.

But, if I store a Datatable. Is it possible to get one DataTable Field from session without fetching the whole DataTable?

For Eg,

If I have col1,col2, col3 in DataTable dt and I store it in session.

Is it possible to fetch col2 from DataTable which is in Session without
creating a new Datatable?

Is something like this possible: Session["dt"]["col2"]?

Without Doing this:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

dt1 = (DataTable) Session["dt"];
```

Comment: The structure is the datatable itself. `dt1 = (DataTable) Session["dt"];` replaces whatever is stored in `dt1` so there's no reason to use `DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();`, you can use `var dt1 = (DataTable) Session["dt"];`. If you want to use a field, you can use the rather ugly `var value = ((DataTable) Session["dt"]).Rows[0]["SomeField"];` or store the DataTable in a variable first, then use `var value=dt1.Rows[0]["SomeField"];`

Comment: In any case, how the DataTable is stored has nothing to do with how you call it when you retrieve it from the session

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to fetch col2 from DataTable which is in Session without creating a new Datatable?

Yes. You don't need to create *new DataTable()*

> Is something like this possible: Session["dt"]["col2"]?

No. You will need to typecast it before using any of the `DataTable` properties. So typically you will do something like:

```
DataTable dt1 = (DataTable) Session["dt"];
```

And then use `dt1` to do the rest of the processing.

Comment: How can I do it on .aspx page?